# how to upload images using flask and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I am new to Flask and I have an easy question
how to upload images using ajax in Flask, I tried the below code and it seems that the form data is empty and always stuck on response with the message  "Presentation Not Found .."
I tried mode different code and always failed

my code here :

```
@presentation.route('/presentation/updateImage',methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def updateImage() :
    message=''
    status=''

    updateImageForm = UpdateImage()
    if updateImageForm.validate_on_submit() :
        id        = request.json.get('id')
        action    = request.json.get('action')
        image     = request.json.get('image')
        presentaion = Presentaions.query.filter_by(deleted=1,id=id).first()
        if  presentaion ==None :
                return jsonify({'status':'apperror','message': 'Pressentaion  Not Found ..'})
        presentaion.image = uploadMainPresntaionImage(image,id)
        presentaion.last_updated_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        presentaion.last_updated_by = current_user.id
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'status': "success", 'message': 'Password Changed Successfuly'})               
    else:   
        errors = {}
        for field, field_errors in updateImageForm.errors.items():
            errors[field] = [str(error) for error in field_errors]
        return jsonify({'status': "errors ", 'message': errors})
```

my js code is  :

```
//get id for presentaion
  $(".table_for_data").on( 'click', '.img-edit', function () {
          id=$(this).attr('data-id');
          $("#imageId").val(id)

        });


$("#updateimageform").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault()
//var formData = $(this).serialize();
//var allData  = formData + "&action=editPass";
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('image');
    var image = fileInput.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    var myaction = 'updateImage'
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('id', id);
    formData.append('action', myaction);
    console.log(formData)

$.ajax({
  url: "{{ url_for('presentation.updateImage') }} ",
  type:"POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  contentType: 'application/json',

  beforeSend:function(){
  },
  statusCode: {
      404: function() {
          alert( "page not found" );
      },
  },
  success:function(valdata) {
      
      if(valdata['status'] == "success")
      {
        $('#updateImageResult').html('');
        $('#updateImageResult').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">' + valdata['message']  + '</div>');
        $("#updateimageform")[0].reset();
          setTimeout(function(){$('#update-img').modal('hide');}, 2000);

      }else if (valdata['status'] == "apperror"){

        $('#updateImageResult').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + valdata['message']  + '</div>');
      }else{
        var errors = valdata['message'];
                          for (var field in errors) {
                              if (errors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                                  var errorMessages = errors[field];
                                  for (var i = 0; i < errorMessages.length; i++) {
                                      $('#updateImageResult').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' +  errorMessages[i] + '</div>');
                                  }
                              }
                            }

        //  $("#updatePasswordResult").html(valdata['message']);
      }
  }
});
return false;
});
```